# Azure App Services cannot connect to Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, connection-string

I have an API published to Azure App Services, using ef core, connect to Azure SQL database. below are the steps and the problem:

1. The Azure SQL database is up and running OK, I setup two firewall rules, one for my local dev ip, one for Azure App. I can connect to Azure SQL from local without any issue, and I have done the migrations.
2. I copied the connection string from Azure SQL and put in the appsettings.json, running the API from my local and connect to Azure SQL without any issue.
3. I published my API to Azure App services without any issues, I can see my app running OK since it has static file.
4. Then I went to Azure App Services => Settings/Configuration => Connection strings, create one new connect string with the same key/value as I used in the appsettings.json, based on the document from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-language-dotnetcore#access-environment-variables

But the problem is after I done these, my API still not working, the api call to SQL return error 500.

Anything I missed or did wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you defined the App Service firewall rule?  By setting "Allow access to Azure services" to True?

Comment: Thanks for the comments CSharpRocks, I did by adding the client ip, but I figured that's not the right way, so resolved by set the "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" to True, that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments CSharpRocks, I did by adding the client ip, but I figured that's not the right way, so resolved by set the "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" to True, that works.

Answer (score 0):

For Others looking for the answer I had followed the steps above and it still did not work for me. But when I went to Visual Studios --> Publish --> Service Dependency's --> Add Azure SQL Database That fixed it for me.